# How to count the number of duplicate repeated grid - orbeon 2020.1CE

Tags: orbeon

It needs to implement a mechanism that will count the number of repeated grids and send the value to the dedicated cell (named `x`).

1. If check box - First choice is unchecked, repeated grid is hidden and cell `x` must show "0".
   [image]
2. If check box - First choice is checked, repeated grid become visible and cell `x` must show "1", and increase by 1 for each addition of repeated grid.
   [image]

What expression I need to use in cell `x`?

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand your question correctly, in the second case you would like the value of the field `x` to show "4", because you have 4 rows in the repeated grid; is that correct?

Comment: Hi
This is exactly what it is about.
Important is that the repeated grid should be hidden by default and the cell x should equal 0 as long as check box is unchecked (as it works at present). Repeated grid in settings has a visibility condition - $First choice = 1. When the check box is checked, scenario from screen no. 2 should be realized.

Comment: Got it, thank you for this precision; I've then posted an answer to your question below. -Alex

Comment: Dominik, I see you've posted about having some trouble running this, so I added the source of a test form to my answer below, along with a GIF that shows what it looks like at runtime. And of course, just let me know if I missed something. -Alex

Answer (score 0):

If in your repeated grid you have a field named `first-name`, the expression `count($first-name)` used in a control outside of the repeated grid returns the number of rows in your repeated grid. Assuming your checkbox field is named `checkbox`, your expression would look like:

```
if ($checkbox/string() = 'true')
then count($first-name)
else 0
```

You can find the source of a test form that shows this in action below, and at runtime you get something like:

[image: Field counts the number of rows]

```xml
<xh:html xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
         xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
         xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
         xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
         xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
         xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
         xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
         xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
    <xh:head>
        <xh:title>Counting the number of rows in a repeated grid</xh:title>
        <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true" xxf:analysis.calculate="true">

            <!-- Main instance -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:index="id">
                <form>
                    <section-1>
                        <grid-1>
                            <checkbox question-identifier="">true</checkbox>
                            <count question-identifier=""/>
                        </grid-1>
                        <grid-2>
                            <grid-2-iteration>
                                <first-name question-identifier=""/>
                            </grid-2-iteration>
                        </grid-2>
                        
                    </section-1>
                </form>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- Bindings -->
            <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
                <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                    <xf:bind id="grid-1-bind" ref="grid-1" name="grid-1">
                        <xf:bind id="count-bind" name="count" ref="count" xxf:whitespace="trim"
                                 calculate="if ($checkbox/string() = 'true')&#xA;then count($first-name)&#xA;else 0"
                                 readonly="false()"/>
                        <xf:bind id="checkbox-bind" ref="checkbox" name="checkbox" type="xf:boolean"/>
                    </xf:bind>
                    <xf:bind id="grid-2-bind" ref="grid-2" name="grid-2"
                             relevant="$checkbox/string() = 'true'">
                        <xf:bind id="grid-2-iteration-bind" ref="grid-2-iteration" name="grid-2-iteration">
                            <xf:bind id="first-name-bind" ref="first-name" name="first-name" xxf:whitespace="trim"/>
                        </xf:bind>
                    </xf:bind>
                    
                </xf:bind>
            </xf:bind>

            <!-- Metadata -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:readonly="true" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <metadata>
                    <application-name>a</application-name>
                    <form-name>a</form-name>
                    <title xml:lang="en">Counting the number of rows in a repeated grid</title>
                    <description xml:lang="en"/>
                    <created-with-version>2019.1-SNAPSHOT PE</created-with-version>
                    <library-versions>
                        <orbeon>1</orbeon>
                        <app>2</app>
                    </library-versions>
                </metadata>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- Attachments -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <attachments/>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- All form resources -->
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-resources" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <resources>
                    <resource xml:lang="en">
                        <checkbox>
                            <label>Show repeated grid</label>
                            <hint/>
                        </checkbox>
                        <count>
                            <label>Count</label>
                            <hint/>
                            
                        </count>
                        <first-name>
                            <label>First name</label>
                            <hint/>
                        </first-name>
                        <section-1>
                            <label>Untitled Section</label>
                        </section-1>
                        
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </xf:instance>
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="grid-2-template" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <grid-2-iteration>
                    <first-name/>
                </grid-2-iteration>
            </xf:instance>

        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <fr:view>
            <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                     xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
                <fr:section id="section-1-section" bind="section-1-bind">
                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                    <fr:grid id="grid-1-grid" bind="grid-1-bind">
                        <fr:c y="1" x="1" w="6">
                            <fr:checkbox-input id="checkbox-control" bind="checkbox-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/checkbox/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/checkbox/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                        
                        
                            </fr:checkbox-input>
                                
                            </fr:c>
                        <fr:c y="1" x="7" w="6">
                            <xf:input id="count-control" bind="count-bind">
                                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/count/label"/>
                                    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/count/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                    
                                </xf:input>
                        </fr:c>
                    </fr:grid>
                    <fr:grid id="grid-2-grid" bind="grid-2-bind" repeat="content" min="1"
                             template="instance('grid-2-template')"
                             apply-defaults="true"
                             fb:initial-iterations="first">
                        <fr:c x="1" y="1" w="6">
                            <xf:input id="first-name-control" bind="first-name-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/first-name/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/first-name/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                        
                        
                            </xf:input>
                        </fr:c>
                        <fr:c x="7" y="1" w="6"/>
                    </fr:grid>
                </fr:section>
            </fr:body>
        </fr:view>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```